# How to reuse Keras one_hot function on predicting?

Tags: keras, one-hot-encoding

I'm making word2vec using keras.preprocessing.text.ont_hot

```
one_hot(['hello', 'world', 'hi', 'nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you'], 100)
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But whenever I run the script, the result changes.

the one_hot encoded sentence I input isn't equal to previous same sentence.

in short, 1st try `one_hot("hello world", 100)` is not equal to 2nd try `one_hot("hello world", 100)`.

so how can I get same result of one_hot function?

Comment: Why do you need to get the same results ? You can simply store the result of `one_hot` and use it everywhere.

Comment: How can i store one_hot result? I didn't find it so i solved it by using Dict and Counter.

Comment: By just assigning the result to a variable. Using a dict is also a good solution I think and I was suggesting something similar by storing the results.

Comment: how did you save it? Post answer please.